# Eclipse Xml Formatting: Have xml namespaces split onto new line

Tags: xml, eclipse

Does anybody know a way that I can get eclipse to automatically format my xml  namespaces on the root element with each attribute split on a newline BUT still have the rest of the file formatted without splitting each attribute on a new line?

So that my files would look something like this:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
              xmlns:util="http://discovery.co.za/mytags" 
              xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
              xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
              xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
              xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>

        <h:inputText id="dateInput" type="date" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
            <f:ajax event="change" render="#{cc.attrs.render}" execute="@this #{cc.attrs.execute}" />
        </h:inputText>



</ui:component>
```

Comment: I believe you can `Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor` then select Split multiple attributes. Buuut not sure what that will do to your XHTML.

Comment: Na Ken, that's going to format the whole file... was looking for a trick to format only the namespaces